# Printing class member

Tags: c#, class, printing

So I'm making multiplayer minesweeper. I am at the end where I want to print score of each player. For player I have a class like this:

```
public class Player
{
    public string name;
    public int score;
}
```

For each client that connects I run a new thread:

```
clientThreads[i] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
```

And then at the end of HandleClient method I have this:

```
foreach(Player p in players)
{ 
    this.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        label8.Text += p.name + ":" + p.score.ToString();
    }));
}
```

I also tried with MessageBox if that changes anything, but problem is that I do get name of a player, like it does print out but score doesn't get printed, even ":" is not printed. I placed a breakpoint and p.score does have a value so its not like its null or something. And I don't get any error neither there is any error shown while editing. What is maybe strange is that even if I remove ToString() there is still no error even tho I am adding text to label.text where it should all be string. I never faced problem like that and I don't know why its happening.

I also added picture from breakpoint. Read "tocke" as score.
[image]

**EDIT:** Solved! Problem was that name had too many of "\0"

Comment: So what does it print?

Comment: It prints name and thats about it. It doesn't even print ":"

Comment: Just a guess -- what's the `name` length? It has lots of whitespace in the debugger -- are you sure it all fits into the label?

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\0` is a "null character" -- a type of a string terminator in C#.

Your `name`s have lots of them trailing, so the rest of the line simply doesn't fit in.

You can use something like `name.Trim()` to get rid of them in the label.